# BigQuery using MAX() function

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

So I have a query in BQ that looks as such:

```
SELECT
  SubscriptionId,
  start_time,
 STRFTIME_UTC_USEC((UTC_USEC_TO_MONTH(TIMESTAMP_TO_USEC(TIMESTAMP(start_time)))),'%B %Y') AS cohort_month,
  UTC_USEC_TO_MONTH(start_time) AS usec_month,
  STRFTIME_UTC_USEC((UTC_USEC_TO_WEEK(TIMESTAMP_TO_USEC(TIMESTAMP(start_time)), 0)),'%Y-%m-%d') AS cohort_week,
  WEEK(start_time) AS usec_week,
  DATE(start_time) AS cohort_day,
  UTC_USEC_TO_DAY(start_time) AS usec_day,
  amount,
  current_period_start,
  current_period_end,
  cancel_date,
  end_date,
  cancel_at_period_end,
  salesRepEmail,
  CASE WHEN (salesRepEmail IS NOT NULL) THEN 'Telesales' ELSE 'Online' END AS sales_channel,
  status,
  type_id,
  CASE WHEN (type_id IN ('150032',
      '150033',
      '150023')) THEN 'Annual' ELSE 'Monthly' END AS duration,
  refunded
FROM
  [data_snapshots_daily.subs_charges_refunds_]
WHERE
  start_time >= '2016-04-01 00:00:00'
  AND refunded = FALSE
```

What I'm looking to do though, is add on to the query so that it returns all the relevant data from the most recent month, week, and day.

So I imagine it involves something to do with MAX(usec_month) but I can't figure it out. Remember, I only want it to return relevant data when it's included in the most recent month (June)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think of something like below

for current month

```
WHERE YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) = YEAR(start_time)
AND MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) = MONTH(start_time)
```

for current week

```
WHERE YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) = YEAR(start_time)
AND WEEK(CURRENT_DATE()) = WEEK(start_time)
```

for current day

```
WHERE CURRENT_DATE() = DATE(start_time)
```

> quick add

for last two weeks play with something like below (should be improved to handle first week of the year)

```
WHERE (YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) = YEAR(start_time) AND WEEK(CURRENT_DATE()) = WEEK(start_time))
OR CASE WHEN WEEK(CURRENT_DATE()) = 1 
      THEN (YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) - 1 = YEAR(start_time) AND 53 = WEEK(start_time))
      ELSE (YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) = YEAR(start_time) AND WEEK(CURRENT_DATE()) - 1 = WEEK(start_time))
    END
```

> Breakdown of above statement (per your request)

It looks for starttime that either belong to current or previous week. Current week is straightforward. In case of previous week it looks if current week is not the first week of the year - in this case condition is - same year but previous week. And in case if current week is first week of the year - it looks for last week of previous year.

> cleaner version to handle `last two weeks` condition

```
DATE(start_time)>DATE(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(),-7*1-DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE()),'DAY'))
```

changing `1` in `7*1` to let's say `3` - will give you condition for `last four weeks` for example

Comment: This was very helpful, but I've got a follow-up question. What if I wanted to add in the previous week as well? So basically, it returns the current weeks data and the previous weeks?

Comment: see "quick add" in answer

Comment: Worked! Thanks!

Though I still am a bit confused about the CASE statement. Could you breakdown what exactly is happening?

Comment: see additions in answer